# Identify the relation between two object when class stores list of its objects

Tags: algorithm

I have a class `Person`.

It has an instance member List friendlist that stores the objects of class Person, now **I need to identify the relation between two objects of class `Person`**.

For example, `P1` is a friend of `P2` and `P3` is a friend of `P2` then relation between `P1`, `P2` and `P2`, `P3` would be 1 and relation between `P1` and `P3` will be 2.

Comment: a class Person that stores a List of 'persons'. Badly chosen name for your class, better give it a name like 'FriendsList'. Or, in the class Person, have an instance member : List -> where the Friends of the Person itself are added.

Comment: What you need is a graph (in order to represent the relations). And then you need to apply an algorithm like Depth-first search to calculate the relation path size.

Comment: I tried to make it more clear what you intend to do, but it still isn't clear what you want. Is it the name of an algorithm? Otherwise, if you want a program, then its not here the good place to ask people to do it for you. Hire someone. You should also tell us what coding language your talking about. Or is it only pure conceptual OOP?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be easily transformed to a popular graph problem. You describe a relation. Any relation can be shown as a directed graph where two vertex `a`, `b` are connected `iff` `a` is in relation with `b`.

You'll get your answer by finding the shortest path between `x` and `y` in your graph. The algorithm would be `Dijkstra Shortest Path in a Directed Graph`. It's perfectly described on [GeeksforGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-6-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/) web page.

> 1) Create a set sptSet (shortest path tree set) that keeps track of vertices included in shortest path tree, i.e., whose minimum distance from source is calculated and finalized. Initially, this set is empty.
>
> 2) Assign a distance value to all vertices in the input graph. Initialize all distance values as INFINITE. Assign distance value as 0 for the source vertex so that it is picked first.
>
> 3) While sptSet doesn’t include all vertices
>
> a) Pick a vertex u which is not there in sptSetand has minimum distance value.
>
> b) Include u to sptSet.
>
> c) Update distance value of all adjacent vertices of u. To update the distance values, iterate through all adjacent vertices. For every adjacent vertex v, if sum of distance value of u (from source) and weight of edge u-v, is less than the distance value of v, then update the distance value of v.

You can find the full explanation on this webpage. Beware! It's usually slow during common examination as all Computer Science students are there 24/7 :)